# How to redefine forward slash?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\ttfamily
https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The URL is not being hyphenated (because LaTeX doesn't hyphenate monospace fonts) and I'm getting "Overfull \hbox". The only solution I've found is to redefine the forward-slash to "forward-slash with a space" (maybe also do this with the dot). How can I do this?

PS. For some reason, this question was closed, while the answer is provided in [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612377/how-to-redefine-a-forward-slash-symbol).

Comment: @Marijn yes, it does but doesn't work in my case (I don't know why)

Comment: When I try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\url{https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}` it breaks the url (between `stackoverflow.` and `com`).

Comment: @Marijn I'm not using `\url` command in my example above

Comment: I know you are not using the `\url` command but you can change your code to start using this command, because it is an easy way to allow for line breaks in urls. Do you have a reason for not wanting to use this command? If so then there may be a solution that addresses that reason while still using `\url`.